# Basic debugging of Electron apps

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using Electron to build a native application, based on existing code (developed with Electron v0.26.1). I'd like to use features available on more recent versions of Electron, so I changed the version number in `package.json` to v0.36.9 (the most recent one so far) and reinstalled its dependencies.

Now, I fully expected the applicaton to break when running `npm start`, and indeed it does, but I didn't expect the error message to be so uninformative:

```
Error opening app
The app provided is not a valid Electron app, please read the docs on how to write one:
https://github.com/atom/electron/tree/v0.36.9/docs

Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/electron/myapp/build'
```

I'd appreciate if it would say **why** it is no longer a valid Electron app, give any sort of stack trace, or file causing the issue.

Running `npm start` did create a `build` directory like before, which contains several files, just like before the upgrade. From the way it's worded, I cannot know if the `Cannot find module` message is the **cause** of the error, or the **consequence**. And if it is the cause, I have no idea of who or what is requiring such module, since before the upgrade this had never happened.

I tried "standard" debugging techniques, like running `npm start --debug` (the flag exists, but is not useful in this situation), `npm rebuild`, reading the Electron FAQ, looking for any `*.log` files (none to be found), and looking for occurrences of `require('build')` or something similar (no such occurrences). Nothing helped.

**How can I get any information at all about why this is failing?** Every programming language/build system I know of would at least output the source file where the error occurred, and possibly more information.

Comment: try `npm rebuild`. The newer version probably is running a different version of node and all your native dependencies have to be recompiled. I can empathize with the lack of informative error messages.

Comment: I forgot to mention I already tried `npm rebuild`, even erasing the `build` directory and starting over, still the same error.

Comment: That was my best guess. The fact that it's looking for something in the build folder seems strange to me.

Comment: First thing I'd do is compare your app's package.json to the one in the [Quick Start](https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start/blob/master/package.json) to see if there are any obvious differences.

Answer (score 1):

In your app's `package.json` there probably something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron /home/user/electron/myapp/build"
}
```

That's the command that will be executed when you run `npm start`, so fix the path in there to point to the `.js` file that contains your app entry point.

Comment: The problem had nothing to do with your suggestion in fact, but it was indeed in `package.json`, so it was good advice to take a closer look in that file. I'm stil looking for general information about how to debug it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after bisecting changes here and there, and following Vadim Macagon's advice to look further into `package.json`, I found out that the following change was responsible for the complete failure:

- Changing `"fs-jetpack": "^0.6.4"` to `"fs-jetpack": "^0.7.1"`

Now, unfortunately I still have absolutely no idea about **why** that happened, or **how** I could have possibly found it out other than blindingly changing settings here and there.

This is not the answer to my question (I'd still like helpful information about how to debug Electron apps to avoid similar problems in the future), but it does allow me to keep working. That is, if I decide to keep using Electron, which I'm no longer sure it's a good idea.

**Edit**: There is at least one [related issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/294) on Github, but it has been closed and the issue has not been resolved.